# sql query Delete rows that belongs to a user in a many-many table PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have 3 tables

```
dragons
id, name, age, creation_date
```

```
users
id, name, user, pass
```

```
users_dragons
user_id, dragon_id
```

The idea is to make a query that deletes rows from the dragon table that have a lower age than the given and that belongs to a given user using the many-many table. I was planning to use exist statement but I'm a little new on SQL and still don't fully understand.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from dragons where id in (
select d.id from dragons d, users u, users_dragons ud where d.age < :YourGivenAge and ud.dragon_id = d.id and ud.user_id in (
select id from users where name = :YourGivenName ));
```

And for cascade delete just store the id and first delete from `users_dragons` table where `dragon_id = stored id`

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to suggest:

```
delete from dragons d
    where d.age < :age and
          exists (select 1
                  from users_dragons ud
                  where ud.dragon_id = d.id and ud.user_id = :user_id
                 );
```